# Why are there multiple symbol icons for the same feature type for raster field in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, attribute-table, fields-attributes

Using ArcGIS 10.7 desktop. I manually entered general landuse types for a field I created. For some reason only some of the feature types are consolidating in the symbology while others are creating duplicates. The field names are exact same for each type, copy/pasted, so its not due to additional spaces, etc.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are symbolising by VALUE and not by your general field.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Could you provide an explanation on how to fix this? The symbology Value Field is set to Landuse_General, and appears as the header in the legend in the table of contents.

Comment: OK the screenshot did not show which field was being used to symbolise so assumption was the value field. so you are using the corrected field. Can you provide a sample of this data?

Comment: what would be a sample?

Comment: A few mb zipped up with values duplicating so in your image you have agriculture  and urban. So a clip of your dataset

Comment: Manual copy paste sounds hard to believe, there are over 7 million records for one of types that looks like Agriculture. Try frequently tool on this field and find a difference between 2, e.g. compute their length.

Comment: I converted a polygon layer to a raster and the raster attribute table displays records for each unique feature type instead of listing all the separate single part features. So it was just a matter of copy and pasting into a couple dozen rows in the table (I think the count may refer to the number of cells the features cover). But I started with a new general land use field and no duplicates so it was likely some error on my part when manually entering the first round.